# Why are dynamic networks probabilistic?

Tags: network-flow, network

I have a only survey level background in network science but am interested in it. I was browsing wikipedia and read this page, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_network_analysis.) 
In that article nodes are described as probabilistic.  Is it because of the non discrete time in DNA, or something else? I don't really know why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really suggest reading thi link. It explains quite well.

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rraj/Talks/DynamicNetworks/DYNAMO/IntroDynamicNetworks.pdf